# "I am agreed" or "I agree"

Tags: differences

When should we say "I am agreed (...)" and when should we say "I agree (...)"?

When having a discussion with a colleague, after I expressed my opinion on a topic, he replied: "Agreed". I am not sure if it is correct to add the "d" there or not . But it does feel very natural to me.

Comment: *X [be] agreed* has the sense of agreement among all the parties in *X*. "I am agreed" means that all the parties making up the "I" agree (perhaps, say, your head and your heart, though still something of a stretch).

Comment: 'I am in agreement' is the idiomatic saying. That is to say, I am in agreement with the other party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Agreed" on its own (and in the past tense) conveys agreement with the other party or parties.

> **agreed** *adjective*
>   1.1 (of two or more parties) holding the same view or opinion on something.
>   ‘all the republics are agreed on the necessity of a common defence policy’
>   (with clause) ‘we are agreed that what is needed is a catchy title’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agreed)